# Nodejs problems with multiple instances in production and module.parent

Tags: node.js, module, instance, production

1. What is the responsibility of the `module.parent` below ?

   ```
   if(!module.parent) {
      app.listen(8080)
   }
   ```

Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Only one instance can listen to one port at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

> Which problem will happen while running with multiple instances in production ?

On the same host, you can't have multiple servers listening to the same port.  To run multiple instances of a server on the same host, you need either something like the clustering module (which manages splitting incoming connections between multiple processes for you) or you need to run each server on a separate port and use a load balancer to split incoming requests betweeen the different ports of the different servers.

> What is the responsibility of the module.parent below ?

If a module was loaded directly from the command line as in `node foo.js`, then `module.parent` will be `null`.  If a module was loaded by another module via `require()`, then `module.parent` will contain the module it was loaded by.  There are a number of things this might be used for.  In some cases, it can be used to decide whether to run a code test (when the module is run by itself).

As for why its being used in your particular code example, we would need a lot more code context to know why they're doing that.  Likely it is a module that cn either be run stand-alone or can be used as a helper for an existing server and it uses this to know which it is being run as.